# Xpath getting numeric value in a table

Tags: xpath

I need help, im new to xpath. I want to extract data from a xml below is my xpath.

**Xml :**
`<td class="pprice" style xpath="1">$4,124,000 </td>==$0`

**Xpath:**
`//table/tbody//tr//td[[@class="pprice"]<1000000]`

How to get price less than `1,000,000`, I always get an error NA.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below :-

```
//td[@class='pprice'][. > 4124000]
```

OR

```
//table/tbody//tr//td[[@class="pprice"][. > 4124000]
```

OR

You can use `translate` keyword of XPath as

```
translate(.,translate(., '0123456789,', ''), '')
```

The output will be

```
4,266,240678,260825,0002,185,000589,0007,789,4723,375,0007,780,0001,972,0002,560,0002,541,0001,523,5003,975,0002,845,0004,124,0004,111,0000
```

OR

```
translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')
```

It will return

```
42662406782608250002185000589000778947233750007780000197200025600002541000152350039750002845000412400041110000
```

You can specify your element location as below:

```
//td[@class='pprice']/translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')
```

OR more specific like below:

```
//table/tbody//tr[2]//td[@class='pprice']‌​/translate(.,translate(., '0123456789', ''), '')
```

Additionally, you can use any below function of XPath mentioned in below URL

https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lapalme/ForestInsteadOfTheTrees/HTML/ch04s02.html

[image]

Comment: I tried it but i converted the string to numeric first

Comment: Yes, you have to other wise it will throw the error. If you are using any language then get the data first. remove dollar sign and commas and evaluate it with in the function. like selenium can perfrom the same thing with any avaiable binding

Comment: Sir im only using the xpath and put it in google sheet to get the tables. With the xpath having the substring after i already remove the dollar sign and it is already numeric but the problem only one record is uploaded to the google sheet. Im using google importxml Sir Shubham

Comment: does your XPath return more than one value ? check it by http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi  ...  paste your DOM here.. select XPATH 3.0 and submit ... if the XPath is returning only one value then your need to reconstruct your xpath

Comment: This is the xpath Sir xpath is not converted to numeric and below is the result.
$4,266,240
$678,260
$825,000
$2,185,000
$589,000
$7,789,472
$3,375,000
$7,780,000
$1,972,000
$2,560,000
$2,541,000
$1,523,500
$3,975,000
$2,845,000
$4,124,000
$4,111,000

Comment: That is why i want to convert it to numeric so that before i upload to google sheet only those with matching the criteria like >= 25000000 and <=65000000. But when i put the substring it is numeric but only one record appear and cannot put the greater than operator sir

Comment: It throws only one value now when i converted it to numeric and without the dollar sign sir

Comment: Hi Sir Shubham its me again. How can i show all the tables it only shows one by one by putting a square bracket and putting location of first row. My xpath is this sir "substring-after(//table/tbody//tr[2]//td[@class=""pprice""],""$"")"

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort sir Shubham.

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: Im still checking the function on how to apply it sir

Comment: what the issue you are facing currently?

Comment: This is the xpath sir : substring-after(//table/tbody//tr[@class]//td[@class="pprice"],"$"). But it throws only one record

Comment: Ive tried but still throws one row with correct value sir this is the xpath : translate(//table/tbody//tr[@class]//td[@class="pprice"],"$","")

Comment: do you have one tr with same one long string or multiple tr with indivisual data

Comment: There are multiple tr sir which i think those are rows.

Comment: That's why you are getting one value because you are using tr[2] which means 2nd position tr only ...

Comment: I already removed the tr[2] i just tested it if it throws only one row then tried tr[@*] i think this is a wrong syntax

Comment: Is it maybe possible that operators in xpath do the process one row at a time like using the translate it only replace one at a time?

Comment: If you can post your full dom in post then tomorrow morning I will create xpath for you as it's around 3AM in india

Comment: Yes sir i will try to copy the whole xml sir.

Comment: Good morning Sir Shubham i cannot copy its too long its a real estate website sir